# Eclipse BIRT : One Customer ID and Multiple Order IDs, Items, and Amounts

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am fairly new to BIRT, and having a problem with one report style.

I am required to display:

- Customer ID
- Customer name
- All the order IDs linked to the customer ID
- Order dates and time
- Order attributes
- Purchased items

and other information

I'm having a problem because of the following requirement.
Customer ID should be displayed only once if the attribute(Buy/Sell) is the same.
How can I display Customer ID and Attribute only once while displaying all the order IDs and the order dates connected to the ID/Attribute?

```
    Customer ID/ Order ID/ Attribute/ Order Date/
    Someone12345___Order1234____Buy____yyyy/mm/dd
    <blankblank>___Order1234__<blank>__yyyy/mm/dd
    Somebody1234___OrderABCD____Sell___yyyy/mm/dd
    <blankblank>___OrderBBBB__<blank>__yyyy/mm/dd
    Someoneelse1___Order1234____Buy____yyyy/mm/dd
```

Comment: have you tried script?

Comment: Not yet. I still need to learn much about script. I found a post which explained how to hide duplicated row using script which can be applied to Customer ID, but hiding Attribute is more tricky as it involves referring Customer ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a property of table columns. In Eclipse designer,

Select customers column  -> properties -> advanced -> Suppress duplicates -> true

Do the same for "Attribute" column and you should be done.

In [this live example](http://www.visioneo.org/orders-list), columns "Customer ID" and "Status" are setup like this. In this report-design, a group with expression ROW["CUSTOMER"]+ROW["STATUS"] is also created to draw a border line each time one of the key fields is changing

Comment: Did it solve the case? If so please set it as valid answer